# Returning "String" value from Console Application to Batch File

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

Currently, my console application can return Integer values from the console application via the `kernel32` function `ExitProcess`.

```vb
Public Declare Sub ExitProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal uExitCode As Long)
```

How do I return string values from the console application to the batch file?

I want to return string values like `Successfully transformed 100 batches...` etc.

Comment: Are these stock responses, or may there be strings that your application didn't anticipate? If the former, consider keeping an array of possible strings, indexed by a numeric result.

Comment: Do you want to actually *return* a value to some process that's calling the VB6 program, or do you just want to be able to print to the console?

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms (and also in Windows) process exit codes are integer values, but you could write string data to the standard output stream by using the `GetStdHandle` and `WriteFile` functions.

**Update** As requested, I´ll serve you an example.

First, you´ll need to import some more Windows functions and define the required constants. In addition to the before-mentioned `GetStdHandle` and `WriteFile` methods, the `AttachConsole` and `FreeConsole` methods are also required.

```vb
Private Const ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS As Long = -1

Private Declare Function AttachConsole Lib "Kernel32" ( _
    ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "Kernel32" () As Long

Private Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE As Long = -11&

Private Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "Kernel32" ( _
    ByVal nStdHandle As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function WriteFile Lib "Kernel32" ( _
    ByVal hFile As Long, _
    ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
    ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Long, _
    ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long, _
    lpOverlapped As Any) As Long
```

In my sample project, I just added a `Module` and defined a `Sub Main` method - this serves as the entry point for the app. Please notice, that you don´t get any output from the app when running it from the VB6 IDE debugger. You´ll need to compile it, and run it from a terminal window (for instance `cmd.exe`).

The first thing to do is to attach to the console of the parent process (which is the console of the terminal window). Otherwise, the `GetStdHandle` method will return zero.

```vb
Dim handle As Long
AttachConsole (ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)
handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
```

Once the console `handle` is obtained, the `WriteFile` method can be used to print text to the console.

```vb
Dim s As String
Dim numberOfBytesWritten As Long
    
s = "Hello World."
WriteFile handle, s, Len(s), numberOfBytesWritten, ByVal 0&
```

Before finally calling `ExitProcess`, the `FreeConsole` method is used to detach the process from the parent console.

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: @Demodave, I´ve added an example for you (even though you would have found all the required information in the documentation of the mentioned methods).

Comment: Please find the code above in the following Gist https://gist.github.com/matzefriedrich/e49ec7220f76563e9e4f6cdd161e839e